# nsis nsODBC plugin not accepting all parameters

Tags: odbc, nsis

I am using the NSIS nsODBC plugin to create an systemdsn entry.

When I call the command as shown below it works and creates my system dsn odbc.

```
nsODBC::AddSysDSN "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" "DSN=test" "server=localhost" "DATABASE=test" "Trusted_Connection=Yes"
Pop $0
```

Pop $0 Returns "Successful" and in my ODBC Data Source Administrator I see my connection and it works.

But I need to create my system dsn with a username and password, on the forums and site I have seen they say it should look like the following:

```
nsODBC::AddSysDSN "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" "DSN=test" "server=test" "DATABASE=test" "UID=test" "PWD=test"
Pop $0
```

When I run this command Pop $0 returns the text "error" and no system dsn is created.

I have checked the SQL server instance it has the test database, a login account called test which is a system admin account, it is in mixed mode authentication.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong as to why it will not create a system dsn with a username and password?

Thanks in advance
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plug-in is badly designed because it uses everything on the stack as its parameters. It is also a very thin wrapper around the database API so as long as your stack is empty before calling then the problem is most likely a missing/wrong parameter and not a bug in the plug-in.

Calling the plugin with parameters like `"foo=1" "bar=baz"` is "translated" to `foo=1\0bar=baz\0\0` which is what you see on MSDN and that is the C/C++ syntax for a double null terminated key-pair string.

Why is `Server` set to `test` and not `localhost`?

The code listed on the MSDN page for [`ConfigDSN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/configdsn-function) says:

> For example, to configure a data source that requires a user ID, password, and database name, a setup application might pass the following keyword-value pairs:
>
> `DSN=Personnel Data\0UID=Smith\0PWD=Sesame\0DATABASE=Personnel\0\0`

Maybe the pair order matters, I don't know.

Comment: Hi Anders,Thanks again for your help, I will give this a try.